# Extracting values from an xsd(xml schema) file

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd

I have following xsd file(just an simple example) from which i want to extract some values.

```
<xs:element name="ACES">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ADVANCE-PAYMENT-AMOUNT-DEPOSITEDS"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="ADVANCE-PAYMENT-AMOUNT-DEPOSITEDS">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="ADVANCE-PAYMENT-AMOUNT-DEPOSITED" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="ADVANCE-PAYMENT-AMOUNT-DEPOSITED" type="T_GENERAL_DATA_ONE"/>


<xs:complexType name="T_GENERAL_DATA_ONE">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="ST_LEGNTH_13">
            <xs:attribute name="Duration">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="Jul-Jan"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="Aug-Feb"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="Sep-Mar"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="Description">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="Total"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="ST_LEGNTH_13">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="16"/>
        <xs:pattern value="\d{0,13}(\.[0]{1,2})?"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I am looking for some code showing how to fetch the values of xs:enumeration and xs:maxLength values from an XSD file using the [System.Xml.Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.aspx) API as seen [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30109/Parsing-XSD-Schema-with-SOM).

Comment: XSD file are well-formed XML files, so you can use `XmlDocument`, `XDocument`, `XmlReader`, `XPathDocument`, etc. to read it.  Which one that you will want to use will depend on your situation, so it's impossible to say which would be best without more information.  There are plenty of examples for how to read XML documents, already, online.  If you have a specific problem when you try to do so, we'd be happy to help.  At this point, though, the question is too broad.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I am trying to parse the xml schema,not a xml file. I am trying similar to what is there in this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30109/Parsing-XSD-Schema-with-SOM

Comment: XSD **is** XML (just as a rectangle is a square).  The `XmlSchema` class certainly lets you load an XSD, though, so if you'd rather use that, you can.  You didn't mention in your question, though, that you were wanting to use that specific class.  What part of using the `XmlSchema` class are you having trouble with, specifically?

Comment: @StevenDoggart, since when a rectangle is a square?... I understand what you meant, the typo is funny though...

Comment: In the good spirit of SO, you should describe at least what you've tried, etc. I've seen questions shot down for more than yours - I am surprised nobody downvoted you yet...must be Friday ;)... That's why I've edited your question a bit...

Comment: @PetruGardea Hah!  Nice catch.  I'm going to go crawl under a rock now...